# Eclipse plugin change the cell of org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeColumn to drop down box or combo box

Tags: eclipse-plugin, editor, rcp

I want to know how to change `TreeColumn`'s cell from text to drop down box or combo box, just like the XML editor does, when you enter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
</web-app>
```

In Eclipse's XML editor's source page and then change to its design page, you'll see the version row's content column is different from others, it is a drop down box or combo box while others are test box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TreeEditor`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/TreeEditor.html) for this, I think.